# Resistor decade box

Tags: resistors, test-equipment, ideal

I need to assemble a high precision resistor decade box. Among the reason is that 2 of them creates a very reliable voltage divider & that goes along with my plan someday to put together a ppm voltmeter.

I'm glad that this time, resistors are just about the most robust of components there are. So my requirements are fewer. That is, that the resistors have high precision (low tolerance), low inductance, low thermal noise (from Boltzmann entropy), low non-thermal noise & be fairly high power.

If I want the lowest inductance, wire wounds are out. Chips give fair amount of noise. Films/foils are among the best & that's just about what I remember.

So, what type of film resistors do I go for?

EDIT:

So far, nobody's been suggesting the best resistor type to go with the requirements I set out. That would be helpful.

Comment: The more critical part of a decade box is the switch(s) rather than resistors - especially when the least-significant decade employs low-R (like single ohms).

Comment: I'll compensate here & there if I have to for the first few decades (depending on the tolerance I set).

Comment: As long as the throws of the selector switches have the same resistance & are quite low, which aren't very demanding on my part; I can compensate.

Comment: `[for] lowest inductance, wire wounds are out` I wouldn't dismiss them as readily: *Wire-wound and thin-film resistors are often used for their better noise characteristics*. See [bifiliar and "common" wire wound resistors](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resistor#Wire_wound).

Answer (score 4):

I offer this novel option for creating a decade resistor box, without switches. It would not work for everyone, as you can't switch it quickly and seamlessly from one value to another. Some people would want this facility, so it would not be for them. It does however mitigate the problem of sourcing very good quality switches.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9WTwD.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Unfortunately the schematic editor on this site doesn't have a symbol for a connector socket. In my case, I use 4 mm banana sockets. Each string of resistors uses 5 sockets, indicated by the open lines.

Each string of resistors is used for one digit. Choice of the two connections will give all values up to 9 units.

If you have a resistor box with 4 mm sockets, you would need two connections to go in and out anyway, so you can get any value resistor to one significant digit with no extra connections.

To get more significant figures, add an extra lead between the digits. Unless you're spending a lot of money on stable high tolerance resistors, more than say three significant figures becomes meaningless.

You could put an extra 3 unit resistor in the middle, to give you all choices of resistance up to 12 units. This has a number of advantages. You can go up to 10 and beyond on any digit. You have a 10:1 divider readily available.

Comment: (Thinking *out-of the box*:)

Comment: Very creative serial connection of resistors

Comment: If you would need 999 Ohm sometimes, only two connections are needed.

Comment: @Uwe Several decades ago I asked myself what the canonical connection was for such a resistor network, and it's 1,3,2 giving 1 to 6 in all possible combinations. However, working in base 7 is not great for multiple digits in a resistor box. Adding the extra 3 in the middle gets you to 9, so you can use the rather more useful base 10, at the sacrifice of purity (there are two ways of making '3').

Comment: How do connector sockets have less resistance?

Comment: @TempusNomen It's a question of reliability versus cost, contact area, contact pressure. Look at the specifications of some cheap switches, and some expensive ones, lifetime, contact resistance, repeatability. It you're switching kohms, you can use anything. If you're switching ohms, it can make a big difference. Look to your specifications, and to your budget, then make your own decision.